# How to implement jquery get function in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I saw many questions dealing with the ajax post function in laravel and almost none for the get request. I have a button that when clicked there should be some information that is loaded onto the page but nothing is showing up.

My js file:

```
$("#btn_test").click(function(){
    $.get("/test/getYear", function (data) {
        // do some stuff
    }, "json");
});
```

My routes file:

```
Route::get('/test/getYear', function() {
    return json_encode(Task::getYear());
});
```

The static method `getYear` works properly as I tested it separately. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The only difference is the type of request (POST vs GET). Who knows where your request is going wrong. Use your browser tools to debug the request, ensure it's going to the proper URL, ensure the response is what you expect, and ensure your JS has no errors, blah blah blah.

Comment: check your browser console/network tab to see the http request and its status

Comment: I would like the URL to be `http://localhost/laravel/public/test/getYear` but with the code above I am getting `http://localhost/test/getYear`. When I try to rectify by adding `/laravel/public/` to my js code I now get  `http://localhost/laravel/public/laravel/public/test/getYear`

Comment: Either use the full URL, or ensure that you have a starting slash all the way from root. So it should be `$.get("/laravel/public/test/getYear", ...`. And btw, capital letters in URLs are a bit silly.

Comment: looks like you are a problem with the context path of the application...

Comment: try `"/laravel/public/test/getYear"` not `laravel/public/test/getYear` - what it the page url from where you are sending this request

Comment: `/laravel/public/test/getYear` that did the trick and thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments the issue was the url that the request was being passed off to. So the solution was to $.get to `/laravel/public/test/getYear`.

However, if you are in public/{anything}, you could use relative routing such as `$.get('test/getYear')` or if you were in public/test/{anything} you could use `$.get('getYear')`.

Don't forget to make use of relative routing if you are testing on localhost. It probably translates better to a web environment (since you most likely wouldn't have site.com/laravel/public/test/getYear and would more likely have site.com/test/getYear).

Comment: Thanks for that note about relative routing hope it helps others and I will accept this answer.